# 'OnClickListener' is abstract; cannot be instantiated and Cannot resolve symbol 'v'

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.application;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ClaimApplication.class);
                startActivity(intent);


    }
}
```

I have error such as 'OnClickListener' is abstract; cannot be instantiated and Cannot resolve symbol 'v'
I am a new programmer so please someone help!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot instantiate abstract classes, so the new `View.OnClickListener()` gives the error.
As said in the Android Doc (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button), try this

```
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Code here
         }
     });
```

and for keeping the code as simple as possible I suggest to call a method inside the `onClick()`,

```
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             myMethod();
         }
     });
}

public void myMethod(){
    //codehere
}
```